# Xcode requests I use argument label when none defined in function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this protocol which I go on to implement in my view controller.

```
protocol GuessDelegate {
    func userDidFinish(_controller:GuessInputViewController, guess:String)
}
```

However, when I call it, the compiler forces me to type `_controller:` just before `self` (please see below). It doesn't allow me to write `delegate.userDidFinish(self, guess: guessText)` and complains about a missing argument label if I try that.

However, the method signature has no argument label, just a parameter name `controller` with a leading underscore which I thought meant the parameter name therefore doesn't need to be typed out in the call to the function.

What is going on exactly? Is it perhaps behaving like this because it's a protocol method?

```
@IBAction func saveGuess(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let delegate = delegate, let guessText = guessTextField.text {
            delegate.userDidFinish(_controller: self, guess: guessText)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a space after the underscore... Typo, or genuine misunderstanding?

Comment: Genuine misunderstanding and one I won't forget again. I think because Swift is relaxed about other kinds of spacing I slipped up here.

Comment: I'm surprised that Swift gives you the impression that it's relaxed about spacing.You can't even do an assignment with an unequal amount of space around the `=` operator, e.g. `a= b`.

Comment: Swift allows room to write both let selectedBook : Book or let selectedBook: Book. But these are just my first impressions and I don't have much experience with this or any other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a space between underscore and controller

```
protocol GuessDelegate {
    func userDidFinish(_ controller:GuessInputViewController, guess:String)
}
```